# What are differences and the examples of syntactic knowlede and substantive knowledge in mathematics?

Tags: education-research

There is a distinction between substantive and syntactic knowledge particularly in mathematics. There are several definitions for both knowledge. However, what are the indicators and the examples of substantive knowledge and syntactic knowledge such that we can explain the constructs operationally?

Comment: Could you please include at least one definition of each in your question?

Comment: An example of syntactic knowledge is the order of operations. A related example of substantive knowledge is that multiplication is not merely repeated addition.

Comment: As a formalist, I'm not sure there's anything to mathematics but syntax!